# Scrolling and updating divs, others blocks

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am having a task to scroll and update events which are scrolled(i.e. viewed on screen.)

Basically I have some messages (DIV blocks with id) which I displayed on page. Now when I scroll the window, which ever message seen, that need to be made 'read' from 'unread'. How can I do it? if message was earlier read then it will not have effect. If message is 'unread' and I scroll window, then message appearing on screen must be made 'read' with some action(probably Ajax).

How to do it?

Comment: You say you have code, so show it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JS library called [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/). It allows you to set a callback function whenever an element comes into the viewport.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('message1'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    // Message has been read
  }
});
```

In your case you want the handler to be called when the message block goes above the viewport so you could probably use this:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('message1'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    // Message has been read
  },
  offset: function() {
    return -this.element.clientHeight
  }
});
```